# How can I set Eleventy (11ty) to output a working static site to _site folder?

Tags: eleventy

For the last few years I've been using Hexo.io to generate my static site.
When I run "hexo g" it outputs a static site I can open locally without a server.
This is what I want 11ty to do.

After converting my site to 11ty it works great while I'm using the local dev server.
But when I open the _site > index.html it doesn't render properly.
All of the styles, js, and images are missing because they are all prepended with "/".

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.
There must be a way to set 11ty to output a working static site.

I've been researching the 11ty documentation and online to see if anyone else has this issue.
Mostly I see people wanting to deploy to a sub-directory or use something like Netlify.
I'd prefer to avoid that.

I've tried using a URL filter that outputs relative paths using pathPrefix.
But there doesn't seem to be a pathPrefix that removes the "/".

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please check out any existing eleventy template, because it works. As for the setup, there is a simple way to configure directories. With 11ty you get the possibility to fine tune everything, but it'll cost you time. If you don't care about the directory and local asset folder structure HEXO forces on you, then I'd go with HEXO. HUGO is also great, if you take one of the existing themes...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a simple way to do it; I once asked the same question on a Jekyll forum and no one knew the answer.

I think the difficulty is in the folder structure, as foo.com/bar has the underlying structure bar/index.htm in Eleventy (when what you want for an offline site is bar.htm).

When I was looking into this, Hexo seemed to be the only generator with an offline capability.

Comment: Thank you. I do plan on uploading the site to Github Pages. But, I want to keep the source and the production static files separate.  Which is the way I was using Hexo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **configure 11ty** properly. Then also keep in mind, that you need to set up **pass-through** copy for **assets**.

```
module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
    
    // NOTE: unlike in hugo, not the content of the assets folder, but the asset folder itself (with it's subfolders) will be copied...
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("src/assets/**/!(*.scss)");

    eleventyConfig.addLayoutAlias('default', 'base.njk')

    eleventyConfig.setFrontMatterParsingOptions({ excerpt: true, excerpt_separator: '---' });

    return {

        passthroughFileCopy: true,

        dataTemplateEngine: 'njk',
        htmlTemplateEngine: "njk", 
        markdownTemplateEngine: "njk",

        templateFormats: [
            "html",
            "njk",
            "ejs",
            "md"
        ],

        dir: {
            input: "src",
            output: "_site",
            includes: "includes",
            layouts: "includes/layouts",
            data: "data",
        },

        pathPrefix: "/abc"
    };

}
```

Comment: There was no problem. I didn't realize I could upload the contents of the _site folder without modification. Everything works.